# How can a global variable produce an error on desctruction while local variable does not?

Tags: c++, global-variables, destructor

I have a class that I find difficult to debug. The curiosity is that when I use it as local variable it behaves well, but when I use it as global variable it gives an error on program's exit.

For example:

```
A a;
int main(){
  dosomething(a);
}
```

gives `bad_alloc` exception on program's exit.

While

```
int main(){
  A a;
  dosomething(a);
}
```

works well.

I am hoping that, by knowing in what circumstance this can happen, I can get to the bottom of the problem with the class. I tried the class in many context and the symptom is always the same, the global variable always have problem while the local variable works well, always.

**Note 1**: the class has a desctructor that calls a (non virtual) member function called `flush` that writes an internal buffer to disk and executes a shell command to process that file.

```
~A(){this->flush();}
```

**Note 2**: I will try to post MWE while I keep debugging (and simplifying the code). For the moment it will help to know typical cases where this can happen precisely to help debugging.

Comment: What fancy stuff does the destructor do?

Comment: Post code for the destructor.

Comment: @John, good question, it calls a member function called `flush` that in it turns writes an internal buffer to disk and runs a shell command to process that file.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on c-library functions to be functional outside of main()

Comment: Can you post a minimal complete example?

Comment: @Beta, I will while I keep debugging. For the moment it will help to know typical cases where this can happen precisely to help debugging. The class is quite messy, it does some tricks with `stringstreams` and `stream` inheritance (if that helps).

Comment: ^^ Actual code would help. :)

Comment: Something that your `flush()` function is trying to use (of the system libraries or another global variable of yours) has already been shutdown before your static object's destructor (which needs it) is called.

Comment: @John, thanks, that is helping, what kind of things relted to system libraries shutdown at the exit point. For example, file streams maybe?

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't define neither construction nor destruction order for the global objects. The consequence of this is that if there are two (or more) global objects that somehow depend on each other (in your case that would be A depends on buffers and shell execution), the dependent object might be already destroyed when the execution gets into destructor that uses that dependent object.

You need to guarantee the correct destruction order `manually'. The easiest way is to allocate the object on the stack (as your working example shows) or on the heap and destroy it using delete before returning from main (or calling exit, etc.).

Comment: that makes sense. It is the first time I see an object that cannot be used globally.

Comment: I've seen such objects quite a few times :) For example:

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

extern std::string gname;

class A {
 ~A() { std::cout << gname << std::endl; }
};

A a;
std::string gname = "Hello";

int main () { return 0; }


Is not safe, because a's destructor accesses a string which most probably will be destroyed already.

Comment: Re *C++ doesn't define neither construction nor destruction order for the global objects.* Sure it does. Global destruction order is the exact opposite of global construction order. This is very well defined within a compilation unit. Across compilation units? That's a problem, but it's oftentimes manageable. Simply (hah!) control the order in which those objects with static linkage are created and you have automatically controlled the order in which those objects are destroyed.

Comment: @DavidHammen - as you say, global objects are destroyed in reverse order of their construction. That's **always** true. It's **construction** order that's unspecified for objects in different translation units. But once constructed, destruction always happens in reverse order.

Comment: @DavidHammen you're absolutely right. It matters across compilation units only. Glanced over this detail. re: neither ctors nor dtors. I meant when looking at ctors or dtors set independently :)

Comment: @orLcount, if it helps, I think there is only one compilation unit in the whole program. That is the compiler/linker is used only one time. And there is no separate linkage.

Comment: @alfC, each object file (.o) is a compilation unit. Don't forget that a library (.lib/.a) is a collection of object files so that's hoard of those as well. Some of those will contain global objects like CRT state and thus the problem of unspecified order of initialization (and the destruction) of global objects remains.